# I get 42 "cannot find symbol" errors and I can't find a solution

Tags: java, class, constructor, applet

Sorry if it seems I'm spamming this forum but I'm very close to finishing this applet. I created a simple Ball class which contains the x, y, radius and speed of the ball. Running the applet at this moment return **42** errors but they are all the same, "cannot find symbol". A search on this topic has narrowed it down to either a problem with not declaring a variable or a problem with a constructor. I have searched for a solution for an hour but I have no clue where to look. Any solutions? (I use Java Editor)

```
import java.applet.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class BallApplet2 extends Applet implements Runnable 
{ 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
Ball rodebal = new Ball();
Ball blauwebal = new Ball();

rodebal.x_pos = 150;
rodebal.y_pos = 301;
rodebal.radius = 20;
rodebal.randomspeed = (int)(Math.random() * 7 + 2);
rodebal.ballspeedx = -randomspeed();

blauwebal.x_pos = 250;
blauwebal.y_pos = 301;
blauwebal.radius = 20;
blauwebal.randomspeed = (int)(Math.random() * 7 + 2);
blauwebal.ballspeedx = randomspeed();
}

public void init() {} 

// de Thread wordt hier aangemaakt
 public void start() { 
Thread th = new Thread (this); 
th.start (); } 
public void stop() {} 
public void destroy() {} 

// de Thread wordt hier uitgevoerd door de methode run()
public void run () {
//  de prioriteit van de Thread wordt verlaagd zodat hij niet nog een keer geactiveerd   wordt tijdens het uitvoeren
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY); 
while (true) 
{ 
  rodebal.x_pos += rodebal.ballspeedx;

  blauwebal.x_pos += blauwebal.ballspeedx;


  // repaint() update de positie van de ballen
  repaint();
  // als x_pos < 100 is draait de richting van de bal om
  if (rodebal.x_pos  < 100) {
    rodebal.ballspeedx = -rodebal.ballspeedx; 
    x_pos1 = 100; 
  } 
  if (blauwebal.x_pos  < 100) {
    blauwebal.ballspeedx = -blauwebal.ballspeedx; 
    x_pos2 = 100; 
  }  
  // als x_pos > 300 is draait de richting van de bal om
  if (rodebal.x_pos  > 300) {
    rodebal.ballspeedx1 = -rodebal.ballspeedx; 
    x_pos1 = 300; 
  } 
  if (blauwebal.x_pos  > 300) {
    blauwebal.ballspeedx = -blauwebal.ballspeedx; 
    x_pos2 = 300; 
  }
  // als de positie van de blauwe bal (x_pos2) - de positie van de rode bal (x_pos1) kleiner is 
  // dan de som van de stralen van de rode en de blauwe bal draaien beide ballen om.                                     
  if (Math.abs(blauwebal.x_pos-rodebal.x_pos)<rodebal.radius+blauwebal.radius){
    rodebal.ballspeedx = -rodebal.ballspeedx;
    blauwebal.ballspeedx = -blauwebal.ballspeedx;
  }

  try { Thread.sleep (20); } 



  catch (InterruptedException ex) {} 

Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY); }} 

 public void paint (Graphics g) {


// de rode bal
g.setColor (Color.red); 
g.fillOval (rodebal.x_pos - rodebal.radius, rodebal.y_pos - rodebal.radius, 2 * rodebal.radius, 2 * rodebal.radius); 

// de blauwe bal
g.setColor (Color.blue); 
g.fillOval (blauwe.x_pos - blauwe.radius2, blauwebal.y_pos - blauwe.radius, 2 * blauwe.radius, 2 * blauwe.radius); 


g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawLine(80,280,80,320); // lijn links
g.drawLine(320,280,320,320); // lijn rechts
g.drawLine(80,320,320,320); // lijn onder



 }



 // Einde eventmethoden


 } 





public class Ball {


int x_pos;
int y_pos;
int radius;
int randomspeed;
float ballspeedx;


}
```

Comment: Which lines are giving the error?

Comment: We're going to need the code for Ball...

Comment: Two possibilities right out of the gate...You're not importing `Ball` (which you may not need to do depending on packages and such), and you're trying to use a method called `randomspeed` which hasn't been declared.

Comment: @rcook :( I forgot, will add them now...

Comment: @ssantos everytime is use rodebal. or blauwebal. i get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use the variables rodebal and blauwebal in your start() method, but they aren't declared there.  They need to be declared in the class, not as variables in the static method main(), in order to be available to start().

---

In response to an additional question:

I haven't got space or time to explain all of this -- I'm going to give you some quick pointers, and then you're going to have to study some basics in basic texts.

You appear to want variables that are global to methods in the class.  They are going to have to be declared in the class, but outside of any method.  The braces define "within" both the class and the methods, so, outside the braces of the methods, but within the braces of the class.

Your main method is (and has to be) static.  That's different from an instance variable.  The common, proper way to do this is with variables that are instance variables, and that means they cannot be accessed directly from a static method.  So you're going to end up with a beginning that looks something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
  String var1 = null;
  String var2 = null;
  int var3 = 0;

  public static void main (String[] arguments)
  {
    Foo foo = new Foo(); // create an instance of this class
    foo.bar();           // execute a method on that instance
  }

  public void bar()
  {
    // here you can use the variables var1 through var3
    // you can also use them in any other non-static method in the class;
    // changing them in one method will make that change visible to the other.
  }
}
```

Now, read up on the following concepts: classes, instances, instance variables, static methods, static variables.  You need to have all those things down cold to do any significant programming in this or any other OO language.

Comment: So where do i put the variables?

Comment: You appear to want them to be fields of your class not local variables only in the main method.